# How to output data from API in HTML

Tags: html, api

I am trying to display the information from the API on the webpage but I can only see it on the console and am unsure why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>  
    
        <div class="nutritionContainer">
            <div id="name"</div>
            <div id="calories"</div>
            
    <script src="nutrition.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>



fetch("https://nutrition-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/nutrition?query=coffee", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "nutrition-by-api-ninjas.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "my_key"
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = response.content;
    document.getElementById('calories').innerHTML = response.content;

})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Is what you show how your page is actually written? That is, is that javascript really where you show it? Also, note that the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

The response is an array of object.

[image]

Suppose you want to print calories, you can do it something like this

```
document.getElementById('calories').innerHTML = response.data[0].calories;
```

Comment: Please replace the image with the actual code.